# Tailwind configuration not working after setup

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, tailwind-in-js

I have setted up tailwind for my simple web project. I believe my setup is alright, although it doens't seem to change the styles from my HTML file. I followed the docs on how to install. DOCS: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation
My `index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nilton SF</title>        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../tailwind/output.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="text-blue-600">
            Hello world!
        </h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`tailwind.config.js` file:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  purge: ["./src/*.{html}"],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

This is the folder setup image:
[image]

For running my program i use:
`yarn dev`
This is a piece of package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config ./bundler/webpack.prod.js",
    "dev": "webpack serve --config ./bundler/webpack.dev.js"
  },
```

Comment: Hey, I think you are missing the CLI build process. You can see it in the link you sent yourself. You need to start the tailwindcss process first then start the webpack bundle. Or follow this [link](https://dev.to/elfakhalid/your-first-tailwindcss-setup-with-webpack-1gfm) to integrate tailwindcss with webpack.

Answer (score 1):

My package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "npx tailwindcss --config tailwind.config.js --postcss postcss.config.js -i ./wwwroot/css/tail.css -o ./wwwroot/css/tail.min.css",
  "watch": "npx tailwindcss --watch --config tailwind.config.js --postcss postcss.config.js -i ./wwwroot/css/tail.css -o ./wwwroot/css/tail.min.css",
  "publish": "npx tailwindcss --minify --config tailwind.config.js --postcss postcss.config.js -i ./wwwroot/css/tail.css -o ./wwwroot/css/tail.min.css"
},
```

In your package.json you are missing the output path `../tailwind/output.css`

Answer (score 0):

Open `tailwind.config.json` and instead of `content: [],`

add this:
`content: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}'],`

Found here:
https://github.com/vadimdemedes/tailwind-rn/issues/156#issuecomment-1057367140